# Need a basic submenu for my CSS navigation

Tags: css, submenu

So disregarding styling and everything else, all I would like is for a sub menu to appear for some of my navigation selections.

Right now I have a basic list that I made on my own using an online tutorial. Afterwards though, after searching through the web, I still have not found a submenu navigation that is close to my code or understanding.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="navigation">


    <li>
        <h2>Services</h2>

    </li>





    <li>
        <h2>Store</h2> </l

        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>



    </li>
    </nav>


</div>





<div class="navigation blue">

<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Argano-Computer-Services/268377233227887?fref=ts">
        <h2>Facebook</h2>

        </a></li></div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Argano-Computer-Services/268377233227887?fref=ts">
        </a>





<div class="navigation orange">
    <li>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&amp;pc=FACEBK&amp;mid=8100&amp;rtp=adr.~pos.35.195859_-106.672877_Argano+Computer+Services_10009+Clearwater+Court%2C+Albuquerque%2C+New+Mexico&amp;cp=35.195859~-106.672877&amp;lvl=16&amp;sty=r&amp;rtop=0~0~0~&amp;mode=D&amp;FORM=FBKPL1&amp;mkt=en-US" target="_blank">
        <h2>Locate</h2>


    </a>
    </li>

    </div>

    <div class="navigation green">
    <li>
        <h2>Feedback</h2>

    </li>

    </div>

    <div class="navigation purple">
    <li>
        <h2>About</h2>


    </li>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
<div class="navigation">


    <li>
        <h2>Services</h2>

    </li>





    <li>
        <h2>Store</h2> </l

        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>



    </li>
    </nav>


</div>





<div class="navigation blue">

<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Argano-Computer-Services/268377233227887?fref=ts">
        <h2>Facebook</h2>

        </a></li></div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Argano-Computer-Services/268377233227887?fref=ts">
        </a>





 <div class="navigation orange">
    <li>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&amp;pc=FACEBK&amp;mid=8100&amp;rtp=adr.~pos.35.195859_-106.672877_Argano+Computer+Services_10009+Clearwater+Court%2C+Albuquerque%2C+New+Mexico&amp;cp=35.195859~-106.672877&amp;lvl=16&amp;sty=r&amp;rtop=0~0~0~&amp;mode=D&amp;FORM=FBKPL1&amp;mkt=en-US" target="_blank">
        <h2>Locate</h2>


    </a>
    </li>

    </div>

    <div class="navigation green">
    <li>
        <h2>Feedback</h2>

    </li>

    </div>

    <div class="navigation purple">
    <li>
        <h2>About</h2>


    </li>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: That is some strange markup. You can't have a `<div>` inside a `<ul>` without adding it in a `<li>`. And where are your `<ul>`s, your opening `<nav>`? And where is the CSS? You say 'this is my css:' but that's only HTML.

Comment: OOO!!! It's all wrong. @putvande explain a problem.

Comment: Its just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know. But I think he want simple submenu. We are here to teach! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple `submenu` for you:

```
<ul id="submenu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Team</li>
</ul>

<style>
    *, *:before, *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        zoom: 1;
    }

    #submenu {
        width: 200px;
        background: #eee;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #submenu li{
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff !important;
        line-height: 1 !important;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        zoom: 1;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background-color: #77cc6d;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #53994b;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #submenu li:active, #submenu li:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #53994b;
        top: 2px;
    }

    #submenu li:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLggP/1/

Comment: how would I make it appear only when hovering over one of my current navigation selections?

Comment: hmm That's odd I just checked the "this is my submenu section and that wasn't what I had put. Anyhow, I'll post again and see if I can get this corrected.

Comment: okay so I tried opening another post but it kept saying my coding was not correct to be able to post it. The heck with it, he'res my css :'(

Comment: .navigation { position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
  display:block;  
 
  top:-50px;
  
}

.navigation li {

display:block;
 width: 120px;
 
 border-left: 25px solid #202020;
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 list-style-type: none;
padding:5px;
color:white;
margin-bottom:5px;